# Add further special characters to Umbraco Rich Text Editor

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco7, tinymce-plugins

Using Umbraco version 7.3.3 assembly: 1.0.5813.17867

I have been asked to allow a further special character to be added to the built-in character map functionality of the TinyMCE rich text editor used by / in the Umbraco back office.

The new character that I want to allow in the table of special characters is:

```
 black down-pointing triangle
```

, also known as

```
 &#9660
```

and

```
 &#x25BC;
```

rendered as: ▼

This should be available for all rich text editors in the Umbraco installation, so a global approach is required.

I can find this file:

```
\umbraco\lib\tinymce\plugins\charmap\plugin.js
```

that defines all the allowed characters that can be inserted, but it's part of the Umbraco installation. I don't want to edit this file (or its minified sibling) as we'll lose this modification on an Umbraco upgrade.

I was hoping there would be something that could be done with the

```
/config/tinyMceConfig.config
```

file, but it would seem that because the charmap is a plugin to TinyMCE there are no configuration options for it in the global TinyMce config.

Any suggestions would be welcome :-)

Comment: My solution is far from ideal, but what I do is store a copy of the plugin.min.js file in a separate folder, then I over-write the umbraco supplied file in a post-build event.

Comment: I have also created a feature request for umbraco here: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues/4663

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE supports adding items to the character map via the `charmap_append` configuration option:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/charmap/#charmap_append

Not sure how you would add this to Umbraco but the editor itself definitely supports adding things to the character map.

Comment: I have indeed seen this configuration option, and if you create a new Umbraco property editor where you instantiate the TinyMCE yourself you can probably use this option. I don't want to create a new Umbraco property editor in this case, however. You can also edit the Umbraco source file I mentioned and achieve what I want, but at the cost of messing with the Umbraco / charmap plugin source. What I'm ideally looking for is a Umbraco supported way of achieving this, for all rich text editors currently in the site that withstands an upgrade of Umbaco as well.

Comment: Why can you not put what you need in the `tinyMceConfig.config` file?  If that hold TinyMCE configuration data you can put it there.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the config file works, the expected syntax etc... I think that's more the question and not if TinyMCE itself would allow you to (charmap_append is the answer there), but how would you tell / configure Umbraco to add these special characters to TinyMCE?

I have not found any real documentation on how the Umbraco <customConfig> element in the tinyMceConfig.config file is interpreted or its expected syntax etc.